# Play Framework 2.4 with Akka

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, akka

I'm having a Play Framework app when throws the following error when trying to run:

```
[info] Set current project to inland24 (in build file:/Users/MyUser/Desktop/MyProj/)
[info] Updating {file:/Users/MyUser/Desktop/MyProj/}root...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Here are some of the libraries that were evicted:
[warn]  * com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.11:2.3.13 -> 2.4-SNAPSHOT
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings

--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$getClassFor$1.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:67)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$getClassFor$1.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:66)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:191)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.getClassFor(DynamicAccess.scala:66)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.createInstanceFor(DynamicAccess.scala:84)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:612)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:143)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:127)
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.ActorSystemProvider$.start(Akka.scala:291)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:205)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:61)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$.mainDev(DevServerStart.scala:60)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$.mainDevHttpMode(DevServerStart.scala:50)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart.mainDevHttpMode(DevServerStart.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at play.runsupport.Reloader$.startDevMode(Reloader.scala:223)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.devModeServer$lzycompute$1(PlayRun.scala:74)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.play$sbt$run$PlayRun$$anonfun$$anonfun$$anonfun$$devModeServer$1(PlayRun.scala:74)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(PlayRun.scala:100)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(PlayRun.scala:53)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[error] Total time: 13 s, completed Oct 9, 2015 8:06:18 PM
```

Here is what I have as dependency:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor_2.11" % "2.4-SNAPSHOT"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.2"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % "2.3.6"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"
```

Is there anything that I should add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After changing the dependency to the following:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
resolvers += "Typesafe Snapshots" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/snapshots/"
```

It worked!